# May I object to the deletion of my post?

Tags: discussion

The post: [Get List of Directories and Timestamp in a specific format in HP-UX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449766/get-list-of-directories-and-timestamp-in-a-specific-format-in-hp-ux/449951#449951)

My answer was short, because it was the answer of an experienced HP-UX administrator (and expert in Posix shell) to an issue about a shell command.

Generally speaking, I agree with you, but in that specific case, I believe you might undelete my answer, as I have no access to a HP9000 for the moment, to provide complete solutions.

Comment: We strive to have complete and tested answers on this site. If you want to do a quick tip, and not take the time to write up a fully baked answer, and have sufficient rep, I'd suggest leaving a comment, or circle back on it when you have enough time to do so.

Answer (score 11):

Answers *should be* complete solutions, though.

> another way might be to use find with -newer, -older and other options. but it is possible

Is not an answer, so I nominated it for deletion while reviewing posts.

Comment: especially since there already was one proper answer the other one could have been added to...